# NSSortDescriptor doesn't update UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to sort my tableview using NSSortDescriptor in a UISegmentedControl. When I log the Array to sort it shows the correct sorting order, but the tableview doesn't update after calling [self.tableView reloadData];

The data comes from an array which is populated by a json feed. I'm not using NSObjects to display the tableview, it's all populated from the NSArray. See code below:

```
@interface LinksTableViewController (){

    NSArray *data;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *links;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dThor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *theLinker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *anText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *noDo;

@end

@implementation LinksTableViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISegmentedControl *statFilter = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"STAT1", @"STAT2", @"STAT3", @"STAT4", nil]];
    [statFilter sizeToFit];
    [statFilter addTarget:self action:@selector(MySegmentControlAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = statFilter;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(refreshdelay:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void)MySegmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)segment
{
    NSArray *arrayToSort = data;

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pda" ascending:NO];
        arrayToSort = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

        NSLog(@"%@", arrayToSort);

    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {


    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    {

    }
    else if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 3)
    {

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)refreshdelay:(NSTimer*)timer
{

    NSString *myString = [links absoluteString];
    NSURL *JSONData = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];
    NSData *datas = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:JSONData];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONData];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSArray *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datas options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        data = jsonResult;
        NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *bLinks = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *daThor = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *bsLink = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *ancTxt = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *folLowd = [NSMutableArray array];


        for (id itemfeed in jsonResult){
            [names addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"ut"]]];
            [bsLink addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"uu"]]];
            [bLinks addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"upa"]]];
            [daThor addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"pda"]]];
            [ancTxt addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"lt"]]];
            [folLowd addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"lf"]]];
            self.links = names;
            self.tNames = bLinks;
            self.dThor = daThor;
            self.theLinker = bsLink;
            self.anText = ancTxt;
            self.noDo = folLowd;
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    }];

    [operation start];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    static NSString *Cellidentifier = @"DataTableCellId";
    LICustomCell *cell = (LICustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[LICustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"LiCellView" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = nib[0];

        NSString *sLink = self.links[indexPath.row];
        NSString *aLink = self.tNames[indexPath.row];
        NSString *aDa = self.dThor[indexPath.row];
        NSString *theInk = self.theLinker[indexPath.row];
        NSString *thAnk = self.anText[indexPath.row];
        NSString *fLink = self.noDo[indexPath.row];

        cell.ageLable.text = theInk;

    }


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the data for your tableView is in 6 different arrays.

```
        NSString *sLink = self.links[indexPath.row];
        NSString *aLink = self.tNames[indexPath.row];
        NSString *aDa = self.dThor[indexPath.row];
        NSString *theInk = self.theLinker[indexPath.row];
        NSString *thAnk = self.anText[indexPath.row];
        NSString *fLink = self.noDo[indexPath.row];
```

Shouldn't you be sorting all of them? As your code stands now it's not clear how arrayToSort is connected to the data model of your tableView. You have `NSArray *arrayToSort = data;`, but it's not clear where data is initialized or where it's set (seems like you would want to set that in your JSON competition block). You also need to call [self.tableView reloadData]; at the end of MySegmentControlAction.

You can create a subclass of NSObject that has 6 NSString properties call it something like MyObject (but more descriptive). Then do something like:

```
for (id itemfeed in jsonResult){
            MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc]init];
            object.sLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"ut"]];
            object.aLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itemfeed[@"uu"]];
            ...

           [self.data addObject:object];

        }
```

In the JSON competition block.

You then change cellForRowAtIndexPath to include something like

```
MyObject *object = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
cell.ageLable.text = object.theInk;
```

If you go this route you also need to update:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pda" ascending:NO];
```

specifically @"pda" to whatever you name the property in your NSObject subclass. @"dThor" if you follow the naming I used.

Comment: How can I get all those Arrays into one?

Comment: Thank you for your message. I now have it setup like you explained, but the sortdescriptor still doesn't update. It cannot read the array.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your explanation :)